# Generating a dataset along an orthonormal axis using a uniform distribution with a specific variance and mean

Tags: uniform-distribution, variance, orthonormal

How to generate a dataset along an orthonormal axis (of an orthonormal axis system of $n$ axes) independently using a uniform distribution with a particular variance $v$ and a mean $m$?

Comment: You want a multivariate distribution with a scalar mean and variance? What does that mean?

Comment: No, I want a single data series along an orthonormal axis in an orthonormal axis system under a given variance and mean.

Comment: What is an orthonormal axis? Orthonormal to what? If you want your data to lie along a single axis, why talk about $n$ axes?

Comment: Assume that we have $n \times n$ matrix of eigenvectors. If the eigenvectors of this matrix  form an orthonormal axis system, how can we generate data along a particular eigenvector ($e_i$) independently using a uniform distribution with a specific variance and a mean.

Comment: I believe the word you're looking for is "orthonormal basis". Still, why don't you treat this as a simple, one-dimensional problem, since everything is independent, and then just do this $n$ times? A uniform univariate distribution on the interval $[a;b]$ has mean $m= \frac{1}{2}(a+b)$ and variance $v=\frac{1}{12}(b-a)^2.$ So given an $m$ and a $v,$ you can easily find $a,b.$ Now you can generate your first point. Now do this $n$ times.